# Missing Cloud Debugging in AppGallery Connect

Tags: android, debugging, appgallery, appgallery-connect, huawei-account

I can't find "Cloud Debugging" feature on Huawei AppGallery. Anyone know what can be the problem?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cloud debugging can be used for individual app. Select an app and go to project setting and there you will find cloud debugging.